# SMART data: suddenly 491.823 error log entries for SSD

Tags: ssd

I noticed that there was a sudden jump in error log entries (they where at around 3500) with my Samsung SSD, but no problems so far. The error count now increases by i think 3 on each boot.
I am not sure, if I have to worry now ...

Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-69-generic (64-bit)

The output of `smartctl -a`:

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       SAMSUNG MZVLB1T0HBLR-000L7
Serial Number:                      S4EMNF0M727975
Firmware Version:                   5M2QEXF7
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x144d
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x002538
Total NVM Capacity:                 1.024.209.543.168 [1,02 TB]
Unallocated NVM Capacity:           0
Controller ID:                      4
NVMe Version:                       1.3
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          1.024.209.543.168 [1,02 TB]
Namespace 1 Utilization:            187.760.672.768 [187 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            002538 8791b739a2
Local Time is:                      Mon Apr 10 18:22:25 2023 CEST
Firmware Updates (0x16):            3 Slots, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0017):   Security Format Frmw_DL Self_Test
Optional NVM Commands (0x005f):     Comp Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat Timestmp
Log Page Attributes (0x03):         S/H_per_NS Cmd_Eff_Lg
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         512 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     84 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     85 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     8.00W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0
 1 +     6.30W       -        -    1  1  1  1        0       0
 2 +     3.50W       -        -    2  2  2  2        0       0
 3 -   0.0760W       -        -    3  3  3  3      210    1200
 4 -   0.0050W       -        -    4  4  4  4     2000    8000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        37 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    0%
Data Units Read:                    31.552.540 [16,1 TB]
Data Units Written:                 26.395.450 [13,5 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 364.413.071
Host Write Commands:                486.184.815
Controller Busy Time:               2.455
Power Cycles:                       1.639
Power On Hours:                     3.674
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   375
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      491.823
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Temperature Sensor 1:               37 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 2:               34 Celsius

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, 16 of 64 entries)
Num   ErrCount  SQId   CmdId  Status  PELoc          LBA  NSID    VS
  0     491823     0  0x1010  0x4004      -            0     0     -
```

I also had a look into the error logs with `nvme error-log`:

```
Error Log Entries for device:nvme0 entries:64
.................
 Entry[ 0]   
.................
error_count     : 491823
sqid            : 0
cmdid           : 0x1010
status_field    : 0x2002(INVALID_FIELD: A reserved coded value or an unsupported value in a defined field)
phase_tag       : 0
parm_err_loc    : 0xffff
lba             : 0
nsid            : 0
vs              : 0
trtype          : The transport type is not indicated or the error is not transport related.
cs              : 0
trtype_spec_info: 0
.................
 Entry[ 1]   
.................
error_count     : 0
sqid            : 0
cmdid           : 0
status_field    : 0(SUCCESS: The command completed successfully)
phase_tag       : 0
parm_err_loc    : 0
lba             : 0
nsid            : 0
vs              : 0
trtype          : The transport type is not indicated or the error is not transport related.
cs              : 0
trtype_spec_info: 0
.................
```

The rest of the errors are the sames as shown in Entry[1].

I did a firmware update yesterday for my lenovo notebook (not the ssd specifically), that might have caused this issue? The error log entry count did not go up immediately though.

Does anyone have an idea what might have caused this issue, and if it even is an issue?

Comment: Did you not shut down the machine properly for Unsafe Shutdowns:  375 times? For example with the power switch.

Comment: Yes, this number is probably correct. I had multiple issues with waking the notebook up after sleep state for a while and hard shutdown via power button was the only thing left to do.

Comment: That means there was 375 chances your OS got corrupted.